# PHP code not working and no errors mentioned

Tags: php, try-catch

I've tried figuring out the error for quite some time. Even tried using try and catch but to no avail. The output that I'm getting is "query failed" (which is the else part). Also the code works on a different machine. Can anyone help me figure this?

```
<?php
session_start();

//Include database connection details
    require_once('connect.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection

    function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
    try {
    //Sanitize the POST values
    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $phone = clean($_POST['phone']);
    /*$username = 'Ajay M';
    $phone = '9810827804';*/
    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($phone == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'phone missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location: log.php");
    exit();
}
//Create query

        $qry="SELECT * FROM app_user WHERE name='$username' AND phone='$phone'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_PHONE'] = $member['phone'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: suzuki_home.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and phone not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: fail.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: It could be a MYSQL error which doesn't return anything except if you use mysql_error. You can find information about it in the link above.

Comment: Try debugging the code by printing variables at various points. And see where it gets stuck.

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());` And then show us what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

**`name`** is a reserved word on `MySQL`. So enclose your column names using backticks on your query.

```
$qry="SELECT * FROM `app_user` WHERE `name`='$username' AND `phone`='$phone'";
```

Comment: Can you backup your statement that `name` is reserved word in MySQL ?

Comment: **[`name` is NOT reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**

Answer (score -1):

Error Reporting has to be set in the .ini file, but you can do it in the .php file too:

```
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```